# c++ ostringstream improve IO performance?

Tags: c++, file, io, std

When I try to write some strings to a file, I notice that using ostringstream can improve the performance.

The code below do the following things:
1. generate some random string
2. write it to a file using ostringstream
3. write it to a file using ofstream

```
#include <vector>
#include <sstream>
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <sys/time.h>

using namespace std;

double timeGetTimeOfDay(){
    struct timeval t;
    gettimeofday(&t, NULL);
    return double(t.tv_sec) + double(t.tv_usec) / 1000000;
}

string genRandString(int length){
    string r;
    for(int i=0; i<length; i++)
        r.push_back(char('a' + rand()%26));
    return r;
}

void genRandStrings(vector<string>& allStrings, int count, int length){
    srand(unsigned(time(NULL)));
    for(int i=0; i<count; i++)
        allStrings.push_back(genRandString(length));
}

int main(){
    ofstream fout("temp");

    vector<string> allStrings;
    genRandStrings(allStrings, 100000, 100);

    // output method1
    double start = timeGetTimeOfDay();
    ostringstream os;
    for(int i=0; i<allStrings.size(); i++)
        os<<allStrings[i]<<endl;
    fout<<os.str();
    double end = timeGetTimeOfDay();
    cout<<end - start<<endl;

    // output method2
    start = timeGetTimeOfDay();
    for(int i=0; i<allStrings.size(); i++)
        fout<<allStrings[i]<<endl;
    end = timeGetTimeOfDay();
    cout<<end - start<<endl;

    fout.close();
    return 0;
}
```

On my computer, ostringstream uses 0.016933 second, but ofstream uses 0.132003 second

I don't know why this happens?
Is it because using ostringstream reduces the number of IO?
Does std::ofstream has a buffer to reduce the number of IO? or every time we use `fout<<` it will be an IO?
And, can we generalize this to improve the performance of reading from file?

Answer (score 3):

The second method defeats internal buffering due to std::endl (which is putting the newline character and flushes the stream).

By replacing std::endl with `\n` and flushing the stream after writing all data, the second method becomes faster than the first (The string stream becomes an additional overhead).

```
int main(){

    vector<string> allStrings;
    genRandStrings(allStrings, 100000, 100);

    // output method1
    {
        ofstream fout("temp1");                       // Distinct output file
        double start = timeGetTimeOfDay();
        ostringstream os;
        for(unsigned i=0; i<allStrings.size(); i++)
            os<<allStrings[i]<<'\n';                  // New line, only
        fout << os.str();
        fout.flush();                                 // Flushing output
        double end = timeGetTimeOfDay();
        cout<<end - start<<endl;
    }

    // output method2
    {
        ofstream fout("temp2");                       // Distinct output file
        double start = timeGetTimeOfDay();
        for(unsigned i=0; i<allStrings.size(); i++)
            fout<<allStrings[i]<<'\n';                // New line, only
        fout.flush();                                 // Flushing output
        double end = timeGetTimeOfDay();
        cout<<end - start<<endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Result on my system compiled with g++ -std=c++14 -O3:

```
0.025744
0.0173609
```